# Have an ImageView at the bottom of the RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, image, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView`, and I want to make an `ImageView` at the bottom if it..  Just to be clear, not the bottom of the screen, but the bottom of the `RecyclerView`, so you have to scroll through the `RecyclerView` to get to the `ImageView`.

Does the `ImageView` have to be a part of the `RecyclerView?`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recycler"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The key is to add a`ndroid:layout_below="@+id/recycler"` to a ImageView.

**EDIT:**

You also can try something like this. First create class that extends from CoordinatorLayout.Behavior, then attache new behavior to the ImageView. Remember that RecyclerView and Image View must be a child of CoordinatorLayout.

```
public class FixedBottomViewBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> {

    public FixedBottomViewBehavior() {

    }

    public FixedBottomViewBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof RecyclerView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {    
        if (ViewCompat.isLaidOut(parent)) {
            //attach our bottom view to the bottom of CoordinatorLayout
            child.setY(parent.getBottom() - child.getHeight());

            //set bottom padding to the dependency view to prevent bottom view from covering it
            dependency.setPadding(dependency.getPaddingLeft(), dependency.getPaddingTop(),
                    dependency.getPaddingRight(), child.getHeight());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_behavior="your.package.address.FixedBottomViewBehavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: The `ImageView` doesn't show up, unless the `RecyclerView` fits on the screen without scrolling

Comment: Do you want to make ImageView stick to the bottom of the screen or to the bottom of the layout?

Comment: Note: By using this method you will lose the optimisation and recycling of recyclerview.

Comment: I updated the answer, check it, maybe now it fits your requirements

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Create a viewholder for the footer

```
public class FooterViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    public FooterViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do whatever you want on clicking the item
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> 2) Now on onCreateViewHolder() check for the correct viewholder to
>   inflate the footer or the regular viewholder as appropriate:

```
    if (viewType == MY_FOOTER_VIEW) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_list_item_footer, parent, false);

        FooterViewHolder footerViewHolder= new FooterViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

 //your regular viewholder inflation
```

> 3)Perform the correct binding:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    try {
        if (holder instanceof NormalViewHolder) {
            NormalViewHolder vh = (NormalViewHolder) holder;

            vh.bindView(position);
        } else if (holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {
            FooterViewHolder vh = (FooterViewHolder) holder;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> 4) on getItemCount() return +1 element

```
 return data.size() + 1;
```

> 5) override getItemViewType() to identify your new type for the
>   footer.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == data.size()) {
        // This is where we'll add footer.
        return FOOTER_VIEW;
    }

    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

Comment: Adding a view(imageview) to the bottom of the recyclerview.  It is what you asked for.  If you do not understand please do read the documentation of how recyclerview works.